# VirtualBox - run an ova file from command line

Tags: virtualbox, headless

I have a remote Ubuntu server without GUI.
How can I run a virtual machine with a `test.ova` file from the command line?

I folloed [this tutorial](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-create-and-start-virtualbox-vm-without-gui.html), but how can I attach the .ova file to the VM?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An ova file is a complete archive with all of the information to create a VirtualBox VM included inside it. You would use the command:

```
vboxmanage import test.ova
```

This will create the VM in your default VM location, with the same settings as the original VM. You can change settings using the `--vsys` options to this command as mentioned in the [VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import). To change the VM name you'd use:

```
vboxmanage import test.ova --vsys 0 --vmname <name>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I tried and it is working. How can I connect to the new VM?

Comment: If you're only using command line, you should start the vm in headless mode with `vboxmanage startvm <vm-name> --type headless`. It depends what machine you're connecting from. I normally connect from Windows via RDP using the VRDE port. You'd need to set this up though. how to connect is really a whole new question.

Comment: If you're connecting from another Ubuntu machine, use VNC, If from windows use RDP via VRDE.